# Como resolver Error: Cannot find module 'C:\wamp64\www\sqlnode\index.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Quando tento rodar o meu servidor em node, é exibida essa mensagem de erro, conferi os models e caminhos dos arquivos que estou incluindo e aparentemente está tudo certo. Assim está meu arquivo index.js:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const dbConfig = require('../config/database');
const User = require('../models/User');

const connection = new Sequelize(dbConfig);

User.init(connection); //essa connection ocupa o parametro sequelize, assim conectando o User com a base de dados

module.exports = connection;
```

O erro completo exibido é

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\wamp64\www\sqlnode\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:15)     
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:855:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você está importando o **sequelize**, mas você instalou esse pacote? Se não, você tem que instalar o pacote **sequelize** através do npm dentro do seu projeto. Ex:

```
$npm i sequelize
```

Mais infos: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize